# Error running hadoop: hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.3.6.jar: Permission denied

Tags: hadoop

Whenever I am running hadoop on my VM ubuntu I am getting this error:

> command
> /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.3.6.jar grep /input /output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
>
> error:
> bash: /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.3.6.jar: Permission denied

How can I resolve this?